# For loop with dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make this for loop for each colname in my dataframe but I have an error with group_by method :

**Error in usemethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"**

My code :

```
for(i in colnames(creditDF)){
 distribution <- creditDF %>%
  group_by(i) %>%
  summarise(value = n()) %>%
  select(label = i, value)

 print(distribution)
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you don't have to loop over the columns  simply use `summarise_at` and pass in the columns you want to summarise

Comment: `group_by_at` will take strings, so that's a possibility if you need the loop.

Comment: I don't want to do a summarise for each columns I want to automate it

Comment: group_by_at doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’m understanding your code correctly
You want to find out the unique items in each column in your data frame and print the table to the console

```
for(i in colnames(creditDF)){
 distribution <- creditDF %>%
  group_by_at(.vars = i) %>%
  summarise(value = n())

 print(distribution)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I offer a more *tidy* alternative that creates a frequency table by column and binds them in a single data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  map(~table(.x)) %>%
  lapply(as_tibble) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "var")

# # A tibble: 171 x 3
#     var    .x     n
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1   mpg  10.4     2
# 2   mpg  13.3     1
# 3   mpg  14.3     1
# 4   mpg  14.7     1
# 5   mpg    15     1
# 6   mpg  15.2     2
# 7   mpg  15.5     1
# 8   mpg  15.8     1
# 9   mpg  16.4     1
# 10  mpg  17.3     1
# # ... with 161 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with base R.

```
for(i in creditDF) print(as.data.frame(table(i)))
```